# jdbc write to greenplum/postgres issue

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, greenplum

Spark jdbc write is giving nightmares for data having more columns (400 columns and 200 rows) and even with less columns and more rows it is taking quite long (200k records 30 to 60 minutes). We don't have primary key for partitioning so will use little relevant key(reading from jdbc/transformations has no problem only writing is problem).

- Spark Cluster conf -- 1 master, 2 workers >> 8 cores 32 Gb each.
- Spark sumit command params -- 'executor_cores': 2,'executor_memory': '2G','num_executors': 2,'driver_memory': '2G'

Tried below ways as per other stackoverflow suggestions.

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(url=url,driver=driver,dbtable=table,user=user,password=password,batchsize=20000,rewriteBatchedStatements=true).mode(mode).save()
df.repartition(15).write.format('jdbc').options(url=url,driver=driver,dbtable=table,user=user,password=password,batchsize=20000,rewriteBatchedStatements=true).mode(mode).save()
```

Write to mysql is working fine. Writing to greenplum and postgres  is issue(verified in both).
I couldn't find much options.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error found some parameters which helped improve performance.

1. For Postgres reWriteBatchedInserts=true should be used instead of rewriteBatchedStatements=true(this is for mysql only). This helps a lot in terms of performance.
2. Reducing batchsize helped in writing to database. With trial and error we can identify suitable value for a environment.